# How to mock function to return response with attributes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm messing around with `unittest.mock` and got some problems with it.

I have an object `client` with method `get_messages()` which returns `response` with attributes `data` and `has_more`. I want to mock it to return fixed `data` and `has_more` in first call and another fixed `data` and `has_more` in second call.

In first call I want to receive object `response` with attributes:
`data=['msg1', 'msg2']`
`has_more=True`

In second call I want to receive object `response` with attributes:

`data=['msg3', 'msg4']`

I've been trying doing it this way, but I'm kind of confused, no idea if this is the way.

```py
@patch('Client')
def test_client_returns_correct_messages(self, MockClient):
    MockWebClient.get_messages.side_effects = [
    Mock(name='response',
         data={'messages': received_messages,
               'has_more': True}),
    Mock(name='response',
         data={'messages': received_messages,
               'has_more': False})]

messages = client.get_messages()
```

Comment: Take a look at [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer... Generally my code was fine, but I made a typo: `side_effects` instead of `side_effect` - NOTE THE **s**. It should be `side_effect`. Mock accepts everything, so it didn't rise an error. Will definitely use specs next time :D I still don't know if this is the correct way to do this, but it works.

this is the working code:

```py
@patch('Client')
def test_client_returns_correct_messages(self, MockClient):
    MockWebClient.get_messages.side_effect = [
    Mock(name='response',
         data={'messages': received_messages,
               'has_more': True}),
    Mock(name='response',
         data={'messages': received_messages,
               'has_more': False})]

messages = client.get_messages()
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordig to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)

> If you pass in an iterable, it is used to retrieve an iterator which must yield a value on every call. This value can either be an exception instance to be raised, or a value to be returned from the call to the mock (DEFAULT handling is identical to the function case).

Here is an example of a call, twice, from a same method but with two different answers.

```
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('os.path.curdir', side_effect=[True, False])
def test_side_effect(mock_curdir):
    print(os.path.curdir())
    print(os.path.curdir())

>>> test_side_effect()
True
False
```

Comment: Yes, I get the idea of iterator in side_effect. The problem for me was to return an object with attribute `data` without creating a class for it. I bypassed it by using the Mock class, into which I can add whatever attribute I want. Dunno if this is the correct way to this though. Anyway, my solution works, but I had a typo in side_effect**s**